# Spliting a String inside a column, but keeping it in a format usable for further dplyr analysis / R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I have got a dataframe that contains authors and their genre as well as other variables.

The problem I am facing is that the genre variable is a single character string like "fantasy, fiction, romance". Thereby I can not group the dataframe by genre as it groups for each combination of genres.

I have tried an in my opinion way to complex approach, where I used  stringr::str_split(",")  to split the strings up. The results was a list, which I transformed into factor-type. This gave me a list of factor that I used to redefine my genre column.  The result is still not usable for my analysis. So I am wondering which other approach makes the most sense.

This is the minimized version of my dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(author= c("w","x","y","z"),
                 genre= c("a,b,c","a","c,d","a,b,c,d"))
```

What I am looking for is grouped genre variable, in an output like this:

```
> df
  genre n
1     a 3
2     b 2
3     c 3
4     d 2
```

What I get is:

```
df %>% group_by(genre) %>% summarise(n=n())
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  genre       n
  <chr>   <int>
1 a           1
2 a,b,c       1
3 a,b,c,d     1
4 c,d         1
```

As you can see, the strings are not split up.

What I tried was:

```
df <- data.frame(autor= c("w","x","y","z"),
                 genre= c("a,b,c","a","c,d","a,b,c,d"))
df$genre<-df$genre %>% map(str_split,",") %>% map(as.factor) %>% unlist()
```

which did not bring me any further, as I am still not able to group by genre, in a way that makes sense.

After group_by(genre) i get this output:

```
> df %>% group_by(genre) %>% summarise(n=n())
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  genre                               n
  <fct>                           <int>
1 "c(\"a\", \"b\", \"c\")"            1
2 "a"                                 1
3 "c(\"c\", \"d\")"                   1
4 "c(\"a\", \"b\", \"c\", \"d\")"     1
```

The problem does not seem to be to complex, but unfortunately I can not quite figure it out.

I am really looking forward to hear about different approaches and any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyr::separate_rows()`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(genre) %>%
  count(genre)
```

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  genre     n
  <chr> <int>
1 a         3
2 b         2
3 c         3
4 d         2
```

Comment: This works the best with my full data, as I am not only able to count but also able to group_by(genre) for further analysis.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can first `strsplit` the variable, then `count` it:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(genre = strsplit(genre, ",")) %>%
  unnest(genre) %>%
  count(genre)
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   genre     n
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 a         3
# 2 b         2
# 3 c         3
# 4 d         2
```

If you prefer, you can replace `strsplit` with `stringr::str_split` for the same results.

Comment: Thanks. This is great for counting the variable. But it does not allow me to goup _by(genre) for further analysis, including more variables

Comment: This produces _exactly_ what you said you wanted for output. Are you expecting us to infer you need something more, despite the explicit *"What I am looking for is grouped genre variable, in an output like this:"* ...?

Comment: This was not meant as a critc. I was just wondering if there might be an acutal way to work with strsplit and group it afterwards. Thank you for your help. Ofcourse it is on my side to specify the wished output less ambigous.